# Client Program for RestFul WebService?

Tags: rest

HI, i Have developed a restful webservice sample application, i want to create a client for the webservice, can anyone tell me how to do this? i was used Rest WebService explorer, but i want to know how to create a client and call the methods ?
Please help ?

Comment: What framework ? A lot of frameworks will allow you to create wrappers around your service methods automagically. But calling REST methods really just boils down to issuing HTTP requests, so you could simply do that "by hand", if your framework doesn't support automatic proxy generation.

Answer (score 0):

Since REST is talking HTTP and is language-agnostic, you can use most any language/tooling available. Of course the *simplest* test bed available to you is the browser itself.

Comment: I'd disagree because it is hard to execute PUT/DELETE requests in the browser without any further extensions or tools.

Comment: Fair point. The browser is geared to querying rather than doing anything more sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these tools:

- http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/
- https://github.com/cloudhead/http-console
- https://tcpmon.dev.java.net/ (proxying is helpful for debugging)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Resty, which should make accessing your webservices very easy.

https://github.com/beders/Resty

(see Readme for examples)